# how to Rig / Animate a Multi Lobe Camshaft

Tags: animation, rigging

Hi im Trying to animate multiple Cam Lobes on a single shaft

Like So[image]

and each Lobe is at a different interval to each other which is where I have drawn a blank.
and each Lobe should drive their own individual Valve

Does anyone have a super Solid Solution to this

Here is the File if you need the Physical Camshaft and Valve Setup to help me with my rigging problems

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using  [*Shrinkwrap* constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html)?

Here. the valve-rod is parented to an Empty, which is constrained to be projected onto the surface of the cam, down its own Y axis..

[image]

If the slight penetration is a bother, maybe that could be tweaked out by keyframing or driving the constraint's offset, or influence? Or by having a hidden, slightly reshaped cam, to displace the Empty,avoiding intermittent intersection with the rod.

Example settings.. the Empty is constrained to the Cam, projected.

[image]

Comment: how to I do the Projected Constraints

Comment: Hi,  @DODGE26.  It's a _Shrinkwrap_ constraint on the Empty, with settings as shown in the edit, the sphere is parented to the Empty.