# Rigging and animating camshaft follow-mechanism

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, drivers

[image: Camhsaft]

I'm really new to blender and don't know much about all the stuff. But here is my problem: How can I rig this camshaft, so that it pushes down the rocker arm beneath it, which then puches the valve (and the spring) down.

I already akse a question about that, trying to use drivers, but isn't there any better solution like bones or other crazy stuff?

I am really desperate ...

Edit: It is important for me not to use keyframing because I already have a controller bone for the pistons. My hope is to achieve a solution working directly with the objects rather than keyframing it to an animation.

Here you go, that's the position I want:
[image: camshaft_rotated]

Comment: Maybe you can cobble together something from this post? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199320/how-to-rig-animate-a-multi-lobe-camshaft

Comment: Hello could you please show a simple drawing with the 2 steps?

Comment: You can use a controller bone to control keyframes, by using an action constraint.  (Or, drivers, from copy-pasted keyframes.)  See my answer at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202629/rigging-complex-mechanical-shapes/313826#313826 .  I believe that keyframes->action constraint is by far the easiest and cleanest way to rig a complicated shape like this.  However, considering the limited range of motion possible, Eason's linked answer should also work just fine (it's not perfect for this situation of rotating about a point rather than projecting, but it's good enough.)

Comment: @JohnEason I just have tried it and it works, lets say kinda how i want it to be: parent the empty to the rocker arm and then shinkwrap it. But now, the whole empty (with the rocker obviosly) just moves down the z-axis insted of rotating around the pivot point ...

Comment: I did say you'd have to 'cobble it together' which I imagine will mean playing with your pivot points. I didn't look at that posting in detail, just searched for 'camshaft' from the top of this page because I'd seen it mentioned before on BSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had [a similar issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202629/rigging-complex-mechanical-shapes), mainly because the contact point of the cam was shifting too much for an easy Skinkwrap solution to work.

The most efficient way of modelling these relationships (irregular shapes maintaining constant contact) was to use Driver Curves.
By assigning the valve a driver taking in the cam's rotation, we can map the relationship in a "Given the current cam rotation, how should the valve be positioned" -way.
This has the advantage of being fully independent of the animation, allowing the driving object (the cam) to rotate with non-linear speed and direction.

1. Add a driver to the rotation axis of your valve. Set the "Space" of the target Object to "Transform space". Also extend the expression to `(var + 0) % (2*pi)`, which makes it wrap around to 0° once it hits 360°.
2. Open the "drivers" workspace. While the input is in radians [0..6.14], the output uses degrees [0..360] - and the current axis scaling is way off for that. You can scale the axis by dragging the ends of the scroll bars. You also need to disable the snapping here, as we're not constrained by frames.
3. Insert keyframes for the extreme positions. In case of the crankshaft, there are two when the valve is resting on the left/right side and a third when it reaches the peak. You can duplicate the valve to check which values the keyframes should have (since it is not possible to temporarily disable the driver)
4. Adjust the handles so the interpolated movements match.

[image: Driver in action]
(Here i duplicated the result so we have the same value at 0° and 360°; the first and last keyframe are unused.)

You can then just copy the driver to the other valves. If the cams are individual objects it will work out-of-the-box; otherwise, you have to replace the "0" in the expression by the cam offset in radians.